# In Qualtrics, how to dynamically connect two sliders?

Tags: javascript, slider, qualtrics

In Qualtrics, I would like to establish a relationship between two sliders (using the "Draggable Sliders" question type).

One slider would dynamically decrease the value of another slider by the same amount. The user should be able to adjust only the first slider, which would automatically adjust the second slider and its associated value (which should be displayed and updated with the dynamic adjustment).

Does anyone have a suggestion for the javascript necessary to establish this type of relationship between two sliders in Qualtrics?

Answer (score 1):

Right - you could start with the custom sliders, but that won't dynamically update. It will only force a constant sum.

If you go to innovation exchange linked below you can download an example of survey that does this though.

You have to upload the survey to qualtrics, and the only way at least I'm familiar with this is to go into an existing survey and go to the advanced options. You'll find "Import Survey," which is what you want. Import that QSF file and you'll have a version of the slider to play with.

This is the link with more info and the qsf file.

http://www.qualtrics.com/innovation-exchange/dan-ariely-tradeoff-question/

Here's a link with a preview I just mocked up. Not pretty, but I'm sure you can toy with the css.

https://az1.qualtrics.com/jfe3/preview/SV_6lIzOgpiSm91X4F

Comment: Nice mockup! The link to the qsf file is not working for me, do you think you could link to the qsf file of your own mock-up?

Comment: @Flo - Sure thing, you can use this to upload into Qualtrics.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzOOXvB_6Ft5M3ZhbV9ZTUhubWM

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly.